# Using a factory class for TextWriter than can be stubbed/mocked

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocks

This is my factory class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inject TextWriterFactory into the class you need to test
/// In the unit test, use SetWriter() to set a different TextWriter (ex: StringWriter)
/// Add extra overloads for Create method if needed
/// </summary>
public class TextWriterFactory {
    private TextWriter _writer = null;
    public TextWriter Create(string path, bool append) {
        if (_writer != null)
            return _writer;

        return new StreamWriter(path, append);
    }

    public void SetWriter(TextWriter writer) {
        _writer = writer;
    }
}
```

This is how it's used in my test methods:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test() {
    ...
    var textWriterFactory = new TextWriterFactory();
    textWriterFactory.SetWriter(new StringWriter());
    // inject into the class I am testing
}
```

And in my production code:

```
public void DoSomething() {
    using (TextWriter writer = _textWriterFactory.Create(template.LocalTempFilePath, false))
        writer.Write(template.FileContent);
    ...
}
```

Does that seem ok to you or is there a better way? I plan to use this everywhere in my code that needs to be tested. I'm using moq framework and `SystemWrapper` for other mscorlib methods I need to stub/mock.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In *dependency injection* terms, this factory class has a *dependency* upon a `TextWriter` instance. I would much prefer to see that dependency be *constructor-injected*:

```
private readonly TextWriter _writer;

public TextWriterFactory()
    : this(new StringWriter())
{ }

public TextWriterFactory(TextWriter writer)
{
    _writer = writer;
}
```

That way you get rid of the hard-coded default `StreamWriter`. But there are a number of issues with this approach.

- `TextWriter` being an abstract class is nice, but this abstract class implements the `IDisposable` interface, which makes it a *leaky abstraction* to use as a dependency.
- The class is still *tightly coupled* with `StringWriter`, through the `new StringWriter()` call in the default constructor. This is actually a DI *anti-pattern* that [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann) calls *bastard injection* in *Dependency Injection in .NET*.
- You're dealing with an `IDisposable` here; I'd expect this test code to throw a rather surprising `ObjectDisposedException`:

  ```
  var factory = new TextWriterFactory();
  factory.SetWriter(new StringWriter());

  using (var writer = factory.Create("C:\foo\bar.txt", false))
  {
      writer.Write("append=false");
  }

  using (var writer = factory.Create("C:\foo\bar.txt", true))
  {
      writer.Write("append=true");
  }
  ```

---

Let's take a step back here.

Your production code has *a dependency that hits the file system*.

You need an abstraction to wrap it with, and be able to inject an implementation that doesn't hit the file system, so you can test *your* code; the simplest abstraction remains an interface - it doesn't tie you up with a base class with embedded behavior that you don't want your tests to have to care for.. or worry about.

I would simply wrap the writer with an interface, with the bare minimum members you need for it to work with your code:

```
public interface IWriter
{
    void Write(string value);
}
```

Then I would *compose* an implementation for the production code:

```
public class Writer : IWriter, IDisposable
{
    private readonly StreamWriter _writer;

    public Writer(string path, bool append)
    {
        _writer = new StreamWriter(path, append);
    }

    public void Write(string value)
    {
        _writer.Write(value);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _writer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now you can constructor-inject an `IWriter` instead of a "factory", and your tests can inject a mock implementation, and the mock can know if the `Write` method was called with the expected `value` parameter.

Note that I could have done this too:

```
public interface IWriter : IDisposable
{
    void Write(string value);
}
```

But that would have been a *leaky abstraction* - the fact that we're encapsulating a `TextWriter` that implements `IDisposable` shouldn't be *leaking* into the abstraction, because the `TextWriter` isn't the abstraction, it's an implementation detail: you could just as well write an implementation that doesn't use a `StreamWriter` and isn't disposable - for example:

```
public class FileWriter : IWriter
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly bool _append;

    public Writer(string path, bool append)
    {
        _path = path;
        _append = append;
    }

    public void Write(string value)
    {
        if (_append)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(_path, value);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(_path, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now your production code can look like this:

```
public void DoSomething() 
{
    _writer.Write(template.FileContent);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    var writer = _writer as IDisposable;
    if (writer != null)
    {
        writer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

Now, regarding the usability of this code, there's still an itchy spot: I put the `string path, bool append` parameters in the constructor, because you had them in your `Create` "factory method".

Ideally you would make them parameters of the `Write` method: injecting primitives through the constructor is pretty much always a smell.

---

Also note that C# conventions place the `{` opening brace on the next line.

Comment: Thanks for your time, however I still don't understand how this could work. Please look at my edit.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that - edited to clarify ;)

Comment: Thank you, I followed your idea and passed the parameters through the Write() method. This also greatly simplified  the Writer class, as no constructor or Dispose() are needed anymore (all the magic happens inside Write() method).

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark as accepted, and come back anytime you have more code ready to be peer reviewed! :)